# I need to program in python to warn when receive a list of possible OID

Tags: snmp, oid

i need to write a simple programm, to show a message every time a list of possible oID SNMP is received.
My list oID is:
oids = ['1.3.6.1.4.1.31448.1.1.0.9', '1.3.6.1.4.1.31448.1.1.0.13','1.3.6.1.4.1.31448.1.1.0.14','1.3.6.1.4.1.31448.1.1.0.15','1.3.6.1.4.1.31448.1.1.0.19','1.3.6.1.4.1.31448.1.1.0.23']
The reason is when PC receives one of these traps, there is a problem in device, and software must only show a warning. Nothing more.

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried? Have you even googled? Nobody here is going to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

### thanks for your answer. I understand what you say and it´s so.
i explain what i have done.
SNMP version can be V1 orV2.
At the moment, i can´t paste python code, but i have tested with TrapAgentAddress='0.0.0.0' // TrapAgentAddress='127.0.0.1' but  i don´t receive any message about receiving trap.
When i execute, it only show:
Agent is listening SNMP Trap on 0.0.0.0 , Port : 162

I know that i´m receiving traps, because i have received with WIRESHARK at same time.
I would like to insert an image, but i don´t know to do it. I have tried to paste python code, but i´m not be able to do it.

I´m very thanked for your support.
BR,
Antonio